# Toggle Bolt/Stud

Tags: repair

Complete amateur hour here admittedly. Trying to install a frameless mirror that tilts. Instructions call to use toggle bolts. First mirror went up no problem. Working on the second one, I’ve hit a stud. Rather than searching what to do first, I just kept going with my drill bit. My thoughts were I needed to drill it deep enough for the screw to go in. That part was a success. Problem is because it is a stud, the wings on the toggle bolt have no where to spread. Now I don’t have a stud to screw a lag bolt in as my research now tells me I should’ve done. Moving the mirror is a very last resort as it would require moving the other mirror to be level with this one and there this is very limited space to do so. Are there any fixes for this short of a Time Machine? Thanks for any help!

Comment: use a longer screw

Comment: Ofc if using longer screw make sure there is no pipe or wire behind. You can glue a dowel I to it and the use the screw

Comment: Use a _fatter_ screw, not a longer one (for the reasons @Chris noted above).

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid trying to use a larger/ longer screw fo fear of hitting wires or pipes that may be in there.

Use some wood glue and glue a piece of wood into that hole you made in the stud. I carry around wooden golf tees just for this purpose but anything that fits fairly tight will work. Even whittle a piece off some scrap wood into roughly the roundness and width of your hole. Let the glue dry overnight and then cut off any wood that is protruding beyond the wall and your wood screw will go right in and hold.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two different ways of mounting an item, like a mirror, to a hollow wall, like drywall on studs.

- Anchors/toggles/etc.

There are numerous different devices designed to grip drywall or other wall surfaces in some way. Some expand in all directions to put force on the edges of a hole. Some, like toggle bolts, go all the way through the surface and grip from the back. Of all of these, I prefer toggle bolts as generally the strongest method.

All of these are dependent on the strength and structural integrity of the wall surface. If the surface was damaged (accident, previous mounting of a heavy item, holes cut to route wiring, etc.) and well patched/painted, there may be no obvious indication of a weakness in the wall...until you hang something heavy.

- Screws Into Studs

This is my preferred method, by far. Screws into studs are strong enough to hold kitchen cabinets full of dishes - something I would definitely not try with anchors or toggle bolts.

So you actually have a very *good* situation - you found at least one stud! All you have to do is use an appropriate screw. About the only screw that *won't* work is a machine screw, like the screw that came with your toggle bolts. Typical is a 2" "cabinet screw". The key is a screw that is designed to go into wood studs, so it will have a pointed tip and relatively coarse threads. You generally don't want to use a screw much longer than 2" in case there is electrical wiring or plumbing going through the middle of the studs.

Even just one screw into a stud will make the entire installation much more robust and reliable than if you used only toggle bolts.

Comment: I wouldn't use a screw longer than 1-1/2". Wiring & plumbing can come that close to the face of the stud w/o having a protective plate. Also, cabinet screws tend to be slender, while the OP already has a hole large enough to put a toggle bolt into. He needs a _fat_ screw here, so a regular wood screw, maybe #10 or #12 (or bigger?) will fill the existing hole, even though it won't look as nice as the cabinet screw would.

Comment: @FreeMan Actual screw size will depend on existing hole, if it can't be moved an inch up or down. But also depends on screw being able to fit into the supplied mounting bracket. Looks don't matter - it will be behind the mirror.

Comment: Yes, screw size is dependent on existing hole size. I was trying to give the OP an idea of what he'd have to look for. Sorry, that wasn't clear.